# Why is $\mathbb{P}[x \leq X \leq x+d x]$ approximated by $f(x)$ here?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, definite-integrals, random-variables, density-function

I am reading how $f(x)dx$ is an approximation for $\mathbb{P}[x \leq X \leq x+d x]$ where $X$ is a continuous random variable and $f$ is it's density function, and was wondering why this is precisely. Here is the passage I was reading:

> To connect density $f(x)$ with probabilities, we need to look at a very small interval $[x, x+d x]$ close to $x$; then we have
> $$
> \mathbb{P}[x \leq X \leq x+d x]=\int_x^{x+d x} f(z) d z \approx f(x) d x
> $$

I was wondering why $f(x)dx$ is a good approximation- if $f(x)$ is constant about $x$ then this seems like a great approximation, but what if f curves sharply up over an infinitesimal change in $x$? Why would this not invalidate the soundness of $f(x)dx$ as an approximation for this?

Comment: Nothing in the quoted text implies $P(x \leq X \leq x + dx)$ is approximately $f(x)$ but rather approximately $f(x) dx$ (basically the mean value theorem).  Am I misunderstanding your concern?  How did you come to the conclusion someone is saying it's $f(x)$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring oops I misread the text (didn't see the $dx$); thank you for pointing that out. I am curious how this is the  same thing as the mean-value theorem though?

Comment: As you might know, you can think of the PDF $f(x)$ as the derivative of the CDF $F(x):= P(X \le x)$. So from the definition of derivatives, $$f(x) = \lim\limits_{\Delta x\downarrow 0}\frac{F(x+\Delta x)-F(x)}{\Delta x} = \lim\limits_{\Delta x \downarrow 0}\frac{P(x < X \le x + \Delta x)}{\Delta x}.$$That means for small $\Delta x$, we have $$f(x) \approx \frac{P(x < X \le x + \Delta x)}{\Delta x}\Rightarrow P(x < X \le x + \Delta x) \approx f(x)\Delta x.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)$ is not the approximation for $P(x\leq X \leq x+dx)$. It is the product $f(x)dx
.$

Comment: I see; I now have an updated question about why $f(x)dx$ works- what if $f(x)$ curved sharply up over an infinitesimal change in $x$; would this not mean the approximation is no good? Can this happen?